# Want to know about in adsense in blogging

Tags: blogs, blogger, adsense

i want to know about adsense. Is there any way to create adsense account using blogger.
if not means suggest me the way to achieve it, friends.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> To know about adsense [google](http://www.google.com) it. And Before asking any question on stack exchange read [faq](https://stackoverflow.com/faq) carefully.

What is adsense?

Google AdSense is a program run by Google Inc. that allows publishers in the Google Network of content sites to serve automatic text, image, video, and rich media adverts that are targeted to site content and audience. These adverts are administered, sorted, and maintained by Google, and they can generate revenue on either a per-click or per-impression basis. Google beta-tested a cost-per-action service, but discontinued it in October 2008 in favor of a DoubleClick offering (also owned by Google).(source:-[wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AdSense))

> Is there any way to create adsense account using blogger.

For detail step http://support.google.com/affiliatenetwork/publisher/answer/156883

Comment: To know about adsense google it :-D